# PCA loading vectors and importance of original variables

Tags: pca

If $X$ is your data set with columns $x_i$ representing all your variables, then principal component analysis (PCA) of $X$ gives $$T=XW,$$ where $T$ represents scores and $W$ represents loadings (columns $w_i$ of $W$ are eigenvectors of the covariance matrix).

Can we say that $w_i$ vector represents the importance of $x_i$? Or is this information only conveyed by the scores? I am confused by the fact that $w_i$'s represent a totally different space than that of $x_i$'s, albeit they being the projection of the $x_i$.

Comment: What do you mean by "Or this information is only conveyed by scores."?

Comment: Hello @Hiren, welcome to CrossValidated. Your question is not entirely clear. As far as I understand, $W$ has eigenvectors of the covariance matrix in columns, right? That's what you mean by "loadings"? Next, what do you mean by $x_i$, is it one column of $X$, i.e. one of the variables? What is $w_i$, a column of $W$?

Comment: Hi amoeba7, x_i is the column of X and w_i is the column of W. My question was is x_i and w_i related, then how?

Comment: "Or this information is only conveyed by scores" meant that importance of column vector x_i is conveyed by scores.

Comment: @Hiren, I edited your post to clarify the notation according to what you wrote in the comments, please check that everything is correct.

Comment: 1) $W$ shouldn't be called loadings. It is eigenvectors. 2) $x_i$ and $w_i$ columns do not correspond to each other in one-to-one sense. Your question is unclear.

Comment: @ttnphns: If only I had one (insert monetary unit of choice) every time someone calls the eigenvectors with their favourite term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start by looking at your equation.

As an example, consider a dataset with $4$ variables and $100$ data points, so that $X$ is of size $100\times 4$ (and centered). PCA constructs $4\times 4$ covariance matrix and finds its eigenvectors. Suppose we selected $2$ eigenvectors to perform the dimensionality reduction. Then $W$ is of size $4 \times 2$. Multiplying $X$ by $W^\top$ (note the transpose!), we get a $100\times 2$ matrix of scores: $$T=XW^\top,$$ or spelled out:

$$\underbrace{\left(\begin{array}{cc} |&|\\|&|\\t_1&t_2\\|&|\\|&|\end{array}\right)}_T=\underbrace{\left(\begin{array}{cc} |&|&|&|\\|&|&|&|\\x_1&x_2&x_3&x_4\\|&|&|&|\\|&|&|&|\end{array}\right)}_X\cdot {\underbrace{\left(\begin{array}{cc} |&|\\w_1&w_2\\|&|\end{array}\right)}_W}^\top.$$

> Can we say that $w_i$ vector represents the importance of $x_i$?

Absolutely not! In my example, there are four $x_i$ variables, but only two $w$ vectors. There is no correspondence between a particular $x_k$ and $w_k$ at all.

> Or is this information only conveyed by the scores?

No! Scores $T$ don't tell you *anything* about the importance of the original variables.

---

**In fact, nothing in PCA tells you about the "importance" of the original variables.**

PCA *is* sometimes used for feature selection, see here: [Using principal component analysis (PCA) for feature selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27300) -- this is based on the assumption that the variables contributing most to PC1 are most "important", i.e. it is the elements of $w_1$ that reflect the "importance" of the original variables. However, there is no guarantee that this assumption should always be reasonable.