# What to do with principal components?

Tags: pca

I'm running some basic R and there are a lot of great tutorials about PCA but they always stop once they've obtained a biplot.

My question is what do you do with the principal components? I have two principal components that explain 95% of the data. How do I use them for further data analysis or is the biplot the endgame with them?

[image: Scree plot of iris data, pca]

[image: biplot]

Comment: You might find this to be of interest: [Using principal component analysis (PCA) for feature selection](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/27300/).

Comment: I corrected the spelling of "principle" to "principal".  Shockingly, someone at Yale made the same spelling error  http://www.yale.edu/ceo/Documentation/PCA_Outline.pdf .

Comment: This is a strange question: why are you performing PCA if you have no idea what you want to do with it??

Comment: Voting to close as too broad, following @whuber's comment.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable question to me. The OP is clearly running PCA to learn more about PCA, statistics & R. A quickie overview of the uses of PCA seems like a reasonable thing to have on the site.