# Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) for feature selection

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, svd

I was reading a paper called "Production Optimization Using Machine Learning in Bakken Shale", and came across an approach I was a bit puzzled by. Unfortunately, the paper is behind a paywall, but I will explain the case:

The researchers have a dataset with 14 predictors, representing different geological properties, well-design properties, etc. In order to conduct feature selection, they first run a Singular Value Decomposition (SVD), and state that "eight principal components can explain more than 90% of total input variance":

[image: SVD plot]

Further they run a Random Forest (RF) with all 14 features, and rank the features according to their Variable Importance score. Additionally, they perform Recursive Feature Elimination (RFE) which also ranks the features.

After this, they refer to the output from the SVD and state "as eight input parameters would be enough, the features we select for our deep learning model are:", and then they list the 8 features that were ranked highest over the two abovementioned methods (RF and RFE).

My question is: Is this a valid way of utilizing the output from a Singular Value Decomposition? I figured these "eight principal components" would be some kind of transformed versions of the original variables, thus not making it directly valid to apply this insight to the variables in their original form. Please correct me if I'm wrong!

Answer (score 3):

[PCA is related to SVD](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134282/relationship-between-svd-and-pca-how-to-use-svd-to-perform-pca), so your general question is answered in the [Using principal component analysis (PCA) for feature selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27300/using-principal-component-analysis-pca-for-feature-selection) thread.

In the paper, the authors give following rationale for feature selection:

> Feature  selection  can  facilitate  data  visualization/understanding
>   and  improve  prediction  performance by reducing redundant input
>   dimension (Guyon and Elisseeff 2003). In our study, we used  the
>   combination of several methods (listed below) to select the useful
>   features for prediction.

Those may be valid arguments in general, but do not seem to be reasonable for their setting. First of all, going down from 14 to 8 features, for me, does not sound like a great improvement in terms of ease of interpretability and visualization, since 14 is already a small number of features. Second, they've used neural network, that is already a "black box" model that is harder to interpret, same with random forest where it is not feasible to draw all the trees in the forest and interpret them directly. In cases of both neural networks and random forests, there are indirect methods for measuring feature interpretability, that would work the same, and be equally interpretable, no matter if they used 8 or 14 features. Third, neither random forest, nor neural networks have problems with redundant features. Both of the algorithms can deal by itself with "selecting" the appropriate features. I'm not saying that feature selection is for no use with those algorithms, but that is unlikely the case if you have only 14 variables.

Comment: (+1) It’s well known that whitening the inputs to a FFNN can speed optimization, so I wonder how much their results depend on the speedier descent to a minimum in the whitened inputs compared to the original inputs.

Answer (score 0):

> I figured these "eight principal components" would be some kind of
> transformed versions of the original variables, thus not making it
> directly valid to apply this insight to the variables in their
> original form. Please correct me if I'm wrong!

it depends on the fitting tool (package, library, solver implemented) that you're using. With Python `sklearn` you can use [sklearn.decomposition.PCA](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) - with this class you can find `pca.explained_variance_ratio_` and if then you need to return from components to the original space of your data you can use `inverse_transform(X)` after you have done `transform(X)`- dimensionality reduction to X ([explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42167907/understanding-scikitlearn-pca-transform-function-in-python))

> When you call transform you're asking sklearn to actually do the
> projection. That is, you are asking it to project each row of your
> data into the vector space that was learned when fit was called.